# Rails 3 gem for tracking legal agreements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

For an application I'm building, I need users to agree to our terms and conditions before we can authorize their account.  Things are a bit complex though, in that certain details of the terms and conditions are dynamic (such as pricing), and change per user.

So fundamentally, I need to generate a new agreement for each user, track their agreement to those terms, and keep a record of the specific terms to which he/she agreed.  Additionally I need to have some sort of terms versioning set up, so that if we update our terms, we can see who agreed to only the old ones and send an update to those accounts specifically.

Writing this doesn't seem outlandishly hard, but I'm curious if there is a decent open source gem that already covers a lot of this functionality.  I'd rather not reinvent the wheel if I can help it.